# Pass info from page to page (offline)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Lets assume that I have an input box on a page. I click a button and whatever is in the input, is transferred to another page and retrieved using JavaScript.

Page1 = C:\Documents\page1.html

Page1 code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" id="user_input"</input></p>
        <button onclick="start_page_2()">submit</button>

        <script>
            var start_page_2 = function(){
                contents = document.getElemeentById("user_input").value;
                //code to go to page 2;
                }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Page2 = C:\Documents\page2.html

Page2 code:

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1 id="my_title">empty</h1>
    <script>
        //on load execute this {
            //retrive contents from page1 and save as contents
            //document.getElementById("my_title").innerHTML(contents);
            //}
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*Note that the input will contain spaces (if that's any help). All useful answers will be voted up.

Comment: You have the form tag, but you are not using forms. Do you want to use forms or Javascript to go between pages? Also, am I correct in assuming do you not have a web server set up on your development machine?

Comment: You could use LocalStorage.

Comment: Cookies won't necessarily help, because modern browsers consider each local file to be its own distinct domain. Because of that, you can't share cookies between local pages (nor local storage).

Comment: if form tags will work, then feel free to help. 
PS: I would be able to do this using PHP, but I want this one offline

Comment: @Wolfdog - What do you mean "offline", you're using the file:// protocol, which is generally not a very good idea, as almost nothing will work

Comment: well, i created 2 pages in notepad and have them on my hard drive. i don't know if i'm using file://, but all i know is that they're in the same location

Comment: download a real IDE, and WAMP, then start creating stuff, it makes it so much easier.

Comment: I'm currently using NetBeans, but when I just want to write around 10 lines of code, I use notepad (I also have notepad++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use localStorage

page1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" id="user_input"</input></p>
        <button onclick="start_page_2()">submit</button>

        <script>
            var start_page_2 = function(){
                var contents = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
                localStorage.setItem('user', contents);
                window.location.href = 'page2.html';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="my_title">empty</h1>
        <script>
            var full_name = localStorage.getItem('user');
            document.getElementById("my_title").innerHTML = full_name;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This only works if you use an actual webserver to test your pages, and there's a polyfill for older browsers on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Isn't it the case that Chrome and maybe others consider separate local `file://` URLs to be distinct domains? You have to launch Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` to disable that security measure. They're trying to defend against hostile `.html` files in installed software packages I think. *edit* oops just read your qualification :)

Comment: this will be my accepted answer if nothing else pops up in the next 5 minutes

Comment: @Pointy - Indeed, localStorage is pretty much blocked when using the `file://` protocol, and so is ajax, cookies etc, and any serverside language is out, that's why we never use the `file://` protocol